# std_logic to integer conversion

Tags: integer, type-conversion, vhdl

I would like to convert my sys-clock (std_logic) to an integer value (sys_clk). Therefore I am using following libs:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

-- code example 
sys_clk         : INTEGER;
clk_clk         : in  std_logic;
```

how can I convert the clk_clk to my sys_clk?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming conversion from `std_logic` as `'0'` and `'1'` to `integer` as `0` and `1`, you can make concurrent statements like:

```
sys_clk <= 1 when (clk_clk = '1') else 0;
```

or

```
sys_clk <= to_integer(unsigned'('0' & clk_clk));
```

Besides, there are some syntax errors in the declarations.

Comment: Shouldn't the second be `sys_clk <= to_integer(unsigned("" & clk_clk));`?

Comment: Yes, you can **also** something like that, but remember to use `unsigned'` thus `sys_clk <= to_integer(unsigned'("" & clk_clk));`, since without the `'` ModelSim generates error:  "Ambiguous type in infix expression; ieee.std_logic_1164.STD_LOGIC_VECTOR or ieee.std_logic_1164.STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR.".  The other 2 suggestions in my answer also work.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you have in mind, but converting `std_logic` to `integer` sounds a bad idea. While you *can* do this I advise you *should not* do.

You don't need to convert `sys_clk` to integer to add or test its value (I can't imagine any use for doing so).

Comment: Further to this - I think its worth noting that as a general rule, if its a number, use a number type like `integer` or `unsigned` and treat it like a number. If its not a number - then use `std_logic_vector` and don't attempt to treat it as a number - because it isn't one! I think its explained well [here](http://parallelpoints.com/numbers-in-vhdl/)

Answer (score 0):

You could also write the function yourself:

```
function to_integer( s : std_logic ) return natural is
begin
      if s = '1' then
      return 1;
   else
      return 0;
   end if;
end function;
```

Then you would use it like you use to_integer() for std_logic_vectors

Comment: I would advice against calling this function `to_integer` this would imply a `std_logic` could easily be interpreted as an integer. It is actually a custom conversion. And you're actually reproducing the `conv_integer` function, which is already in the `IEEE.std_logic_arith` package... [link](https://www.cs.sfu.ca/~ggbaker/reference/std_logic/arith/conv_integer.html)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to to convert std_logic to std_logic_vector(0 downto 0) like this example:

```
    signal ENABLE_std   : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    ENABLE_std(0)   <= ENABLE;
    Enable_int <= to_integer(unsigned(ENABLE_std));
```

Comment: Why not make the type of ENABLE_std unsigned, and then that conversion would not be required.   Note I still prefer @Morten's answer though.